# Laravel | PHP-MySQL very slow on Termux/Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, termux

I'm actually building a Laravel application. I want it to run locally on my tablet. I installed PHP-Mysql through Termux and everything works smoothly, but I have really bad performance.

Basically, the app is a form that is sent. The app saves it, process the next data and show the form again for the next call.

All pages are very slow, even the one with only a view saying « hello world ».

```
Termux: last version from F-Droid
PHP: 8.2.6
MySQL: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.3-MariaDB for Android (aarch64) using EditLine wrapper
Laravel: 10.11.0
Hardware: Galaxy Tab S8
```

With Laravel Sail on my x86 (Linux), the app loads almost instantaneously. But on my Galaxy Tab S8, it takes multiple seconds for each page load in Firefox, just like if there was a network issue/firewall before reaching my local stack. (It's PHP 8.2 and MariaDB out of the box -- no FPM/cache configuration yet) Composer is really slow too.

My question: do I miss a settings or configuration on Android/Termux/MySQL/PHP that makes everything very slow (like a storage access/optimization or something I miss) or is it just a hardware limitation due (RAM/CPU limitation) or ARM architecture ?

I'm thinking switching to a Surface Pro if I can't get better performance, but I'm not sure it will help the performance and has some withdraws for the use I have, so,I'd be happy to get some help on this. :-)

Thank you!

PS: I don't have much time to develop the app, I need to have it accessible on my tablet whatever the conditions are (i.e. with or without internet, and outside walking, so, tablet only). And since the app is complex, I prefer to stay  on a technology I'm comfortable with. :)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "bad performance" --> what query is slow --> then we can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I didn't specify the DB queries because I don't think it's related to that. If I just put `return 'hello';` in my controller, it has this delay of one or two seconds before loading. Same if I unplug the DB in `.env`. 

I guess there's something blocking in the session or storage, but I've no idea what and don't really know where to look.